# issues in installing Cordova and ionic

Tags: android, node.js, cordova, ionic-framework, npm

why couldn't install Cordova... it says power shell is not recognized. What does it mean? and how do I fix it? I have tried some basic commands like
changing my path
System variables > Path > C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\platform-tools

```
npm install -g cordova-res
npm install -g ionic cordova-res
npm install cordova-res-generator -g

cordova-res-generator
rror: Command failed: powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption
'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.


    at makeError (C:\Users\Node\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:174:9)
    at Function.module.exports.sync (C:\Users\Node\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\node_modules\execa\index.js:338:15)
    at windowsRelease (C:\Users\Node\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\windows-release\index.js:39:19)
    at osName (C:\Users\Node\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\os-name\index.js:39:18)
    at new Insight (C:\Users\Node\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\node_modules\insight\lib\index.js:37:13)
    at new RelentlessInsight (C:\Users\Node\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\telemetry.js:31:1)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\Node\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\cordova\src\telemetry.js:39:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1063:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1092:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:928:32) {
  code: 1,
  stdout: '',
  stderr: "'powershell' is not recognized as an internal or external command,\r\n" +
    'operable program or batch file.\r\n',
  failed: true,
  signal: null,
  cmd: 'powershell (Get-CimInstance -ClassName Win32_OperatingSystem).caption',
  timedOut: false
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Welcome!

I'm not a Windows user, but looks like you don't have the powershell cmd on your PATH.

Add this on your system environment:

```
%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\
```